# Need mySQL TIMESTAMP for begining of the current week or any given date?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I need mySQL timestamp for start of current week or any given date, if week starts with monday?

I'm trying something like:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT( DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL WEEKDAY(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)) DAY), ' 00:00:00')) as start
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Monday has a dayofweek index=2.  `DAYOFWEEK($date)` gives the index of the day (1-7, Sun-Sat). So, you need to add or subtract days from your $date's index to change it to 2.

e.g.

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(
  CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK($date)>=2 
    THEN DATE_SUB($date, INTERVAL (DAYOFWEEK($date)-2) DAYS) 
    ELSE DATE_ADD($date INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
  END
);
```

I think I've got the syntax right on this, but check [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) and [date and time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add).